# Validate a field in a PDF Form

Tags: javascript, validation, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a PDF form made in Acrobat X Pro. I want to validate that the value entered into a field by the `user = 'Central'` or `'CENTRAL'` or `'central'`.  If either of these values is entered then the field should be filled green, else filled red.

I've found the code that does this if the `field =/!= null`, but i can't get it to work using the values I mentioned above.

Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() methods to make the characters uniform, then pass your validation argument.

Comment: Perhaps you could help improve your answer with an example.